# Merging records by possible match found

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, ssms

I am running into a problem where I have to correct some historic data. It has huge amount of data.To correct those historic data, I need to merge them together by the possible match found. Let me know if this is duplicate of some other task.

Here is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE Contacts
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    FirstName VARCHAR(50), 
    LastName VARCHAR(50), 
    Email VARCHAR(50), 
    Mobile VARCHAR(50),
    Notes VARCHAR(MAX),
)
```

The merge logic would be something as below:

```
 --When all 4 fields(firstName, lastName, Email, Mobile) are matching for more then one contact, merge them together
 --when one record has all 4 fields, another records has only 3 matching and 4th one as null, merge them,
 --when one record has all 4 fields, another records has only 2 matching and remaining two as null, merge them,
 --when one record has all 4 fields, another records has only 1 matching and remaining three as null, merge them,


 --when one record has 3 fields and 4th field is NULL, another record has exacly same matching records, merge them,
 --when one record has 3 fields and 4th field is NULL, another records has only 1 matching and remaining three as null, merge them,
 --when one record has 3 fields and 4th field is NULL, another records has only 2 matching and remaining two as null, merge them,
 --when one record has 3 fields and 4th field is NULL, another records has only 1 matching and remaining three as null, merge them,

 --when one record has 2 fields and 2 fields as NULL, another record has exacly same matching records, merge them,
 --when one record has 2 fields and 2 fields as NULL, another records has only 1 matching  field and remaining three as null, merge them,

 --when one record has 1 fields and 3 fields as NULL, another record has exacly same matching, merge them,
```

When I say merge them together, that means merge two items into one and delete the remaining one. I was trying to do this stuff via a cursor on the contact list but that is not helping me with all these combination.

I could not find any such post here as well from where I could get any lead. Any lead on writing query to perform this operation would be helpful.

Comment: You could do this with a very long and admittedly complex `where` statement

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help illustrate your rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ever there are Performance issue with CURSOR, considering a lot of condition you can try this below option using CURSOR and check your requirement full fill or not-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=86e332cfbfdaf1f5f13a49f4719337f8)

```
DECLARE 
    @FirstName VARCHAR(MAX),
    @LastName VARCHAR(MAX),
    @Email VARCHAR(MAX),
    @Mobile  VARCHAR(MAX),

    @FirstName_prev VARCHAR(MAX),
    @LastName_prev VARCHAR(MAX),
    @Email_prev VARCHAR(MAX),
    @Mobile_prev  VARCHAR(MAX),

    @loop_start  INT = 0;

DECLARE @tmp TABLE(
    FirstName VARCHAR(MAX),
    LastName VARCHAR(MAX),
    Email VARCHAR(MAX),
    Mobile  VARCHAR(MAX)
);

DECLARE cursor_Contacts CURSOR
FOR SELECT FirstName,LastName,Email,Mobile
    FROM Contacts
    ORDER BY 
    ISNULL(FirstName,'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ')
    ,ISNULL(LastName,'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ')
    ,ISNULL(Email,'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ')
    ,ISNULL(Mobile,'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ');

OPEN cursor_Contacts;

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_Contacts INTO 
     @FirstName,@LastName,@Email,@Mobile;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        IF @loop_start = 0

        BEGIN

            INSERT INTO @tmp(FirstName,LastName,Email,Mobile)
            VALUES (@FirstName,@LastName,@Email,@Mobile)

            SET @loop_start = 1

        END

        ELSE
        BEGIN

            IF
            (@FirstName_prev = @FirstName OR @FirstName IS NULL) AND
            (@LastName_prev = @LastName OR @LastName IS NULL) AND
            (@Email_prev = @Email OR @Email IS NULL) AND
            (@Mobile_prev = @Mobile OR @Mobile IS NULL)

            BEGIN
                SET @loop_start = 1
            END

            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @loop_start = 2

                INSERT INTO @tmp(FirstName,LastName,Email,Mobile)
                VALUES (@FirstName,@LastName,@Email,@Mobile)
            END
        END;


        SET @FirstName_prev = @FirstName
        SET @LastName_prev= @LastName
        SET @Email_prev = @Email
        SET @Mobile_prev= @Mobile;


        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_Contacts INTO 
            @FirstName,@LastName,@Email,@Mobile;
    END;

CLOSE cursor_Contacts;

SELECT * FROM @tmp;

DEALLOCATE cursor_Contacts;
```

Comment: Thanks @mkRabbani. I followed the cursor approach and worked. Performance issues was okay as I had to do it only once.

Comment: you are most welcome @error_handler. Nice to see that it helped :)